# List of relationship. HTML

Tags: html, search-engine, classname, reserved-words

I know nofollow tells search engines not to give credits to the link. And me means the link is a profile belonging to a user.

What are other relationship (rel tag) that are used by search engines? Where can i get a list of rel and their meaning?

Comment: I don't understand this question. I suspect I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

*nofollow* is a **relationship** not a class.

Some search engines pay some attention to some [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page).